# How to add grey shadings to distinguish night from day in a plot?

Tags: r, datetime, plot, timestamp

I have been manually adding shade boxes to my plots to distinguish day and night time using the `annotate` function, but it is tiresome. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Perhaps by having an extra column stating whether the data was taken during day time (light) or night time (dark)?

[image: Temperature data across days with dark boxes indicating night]

This is example of what the data looks like:

| data | days | lightcycle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 37 | 0.08 | dark |
| 37.2 | 0.1 | dark |
| 37.0 | 0.11 | dark |
| 37.3 | 0.13 | dark |
| 37 | 0.15 | light |
| 37 | 0.16 | light |
| 38 | 0.18 | light |
| 38.1 | 0.20 | light |
| 38.2 | 0.21 | light |
| 38.3 | 0.23 | light |

Comment: Perhaps `geom_rect(data = data.frame(start = 0.5 + (-3:19)), aes(xmin = start, xmax = start + 0.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), fill = "gray80")`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877693/background-bands-with-ggplot-in-r Search terms= `[r] background bands ggplot`

Answer (score 1):

We could create sequences, where the nights start and end to `mapply` over with `rect`. I use night time starting at 6pm, ending 6am.

```
(sq <- cbind(seq(-.25, max(dat$days) , 1), seq(.25, max(dat$days) + 1, 1)))
#        [,1]  [,2]
#  [1,] -0.25  0.25
#  [2,]  0.75  1.25
#  [3,]  1.75  2.25
#  [4,]  2.75  3.25
#  [5,]  3.75  4.25
#  [6,]  4.75  5.25
#  [7,]  5.75  6.25
#  [8,]  6.75  7.25
#  [9,]  7.75  8.25
# [10,]  8.75  9.25
# [11,]  9.75 10.25
```

To draw the shading first, we use `panel.first=`.

```
plot(dat$days, dat$data, type='l', main='My plot', xlab='days', ylab='data',
     panel.first=mapply(\(x, y) with(par(), rect(x, usr[3], y, usr[4], col='grey81', border=NA)),
                        c(-sq[, 1], sq[, 1]),
                        c(-sq[, 2], sq[, 2])))
legend(par()$usr[1], par()$usr[3] - .18, legend=c('data', 'night', 'day'), xpd=TRUE, 
       lty=c(1, 0, 0), pch=c(NA, 22, 22), cex=.8,
       horiz=TRUE, pt.bg=c(NA, 'grey81', 0), col=c(1, 'grey81', 'grey81'), bty='n')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 1e2
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(data=runif(n), days=sort(sample(seq.int(0, 10, .01), n)))
```